# Modify TikZ coil decoration

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

Can I modify the existing tikz coil decoration, so that the downstrokes are not drawn in a certain interval, to produce a picture like this?

[image: coil]

**Edit**: Previous attempts, code and MWE has been moved to or superseded by my own answer.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can, but you should post what you have tried so far, so that those trying to help you have something to start from.

Comment: Fair enough, TikZ does have a steep learning curve. But to start, see Page 323 of the TikZ manual and get one of the coil examples to compile (I think the 2nd one is good). Figure out the appropriate `\usetickzlibrary` commands required and try to build a horizontal coil by replacing the `(0,0)--(3,1)` with `(0,0)--(3,0)` and eliminating the rest of the path (also eliminate the `examplefill`). Adjust the coil parameters to get you something close, and place a rectangle on top of it. Now you have something to start with, and people here can work on figuring out hot to hide some of the lines.

Comment: Ok, so I figured out the packages required: Besides the `tikz` package, you'll also need `\usetikzlibrary{intersections,decorations,decorations.markings,decorations.text,decorations.pathmorphing}`. This is the part of these problems that I dislike so it would be immensely helpful when asking the question so that people can focus on the hard part of the question.  Oh, intersections isn't really required for the coil example but I suspect that one of the possible solutions will require that.

Comment: Sorry... I_do_know how to draw the coil, but I do not know how to modify an existing decoration.

Comment: You should input it *before* the `\begin{document}`.  As you are not using it as a TikZ library, you also need to manually load the `decorations` library (`\usetikzlibrary{decorations}`) first.  Beyond that, you will need to give some indication of the errors that your code is giving before someone can help you.

Comment: @ Andrew Stacey: I have tried both - it gives the same error: `! Package tikz Error: You need to load a decoration library.` ,but that is the last thing, that I want since I want the coil from `pm.tex`, so that I can modify it.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen For the time being, just load another decoration library (for a robust solution, you would make your `pm.tex` file a new decoration library).

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: The `missing decoration lib error` was just preventing me from seeing the real problem. -I can not `\input` the copied `.tex` file - see my updated question. Btw - thanks for helping.

Comment: Ah, that's a catcode issue and is because you are merely `\input`ing the document.  Rename your file to `tikzlibrarydecorations.mydecorations.code.tex` and use `\tikzlibrary{decorations.mydecorations}` (in addition to another decorations library as I said before).

Comment: An aesthetic note: you should make the "front" of the rod (as seen from the rod's end) bend the same way as the coils do as they pass in front of the rod. Your picture hurt my brain when I saw it, though it took a little time to determine why. :-)

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: Cool - it is working.

Comment: @Niel de Beaudrap: Yes - I know. It was done quickly(and apparently without thinking) in inkscape, but I do not have the file anymore, so it will not be corrected before it is working in inkscape.

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: I am almost finished - see my solution. Do you know how to use my decorations without loading other decorations? - you wrote something about a robust solution!?

Comment: Take a look at, say, `tikzlibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex`.  That loads the PGF `decorations` module and then the specific decoration code.  So put your code in, say, `pgflibrarydecorations.mydecorations.code.tex` and then create `tikzlibrarydecorations.mydecorations.code.tex` as an almost exact copy of the pathmorphing one.  Then put both files somewhere where TeX will find them.

Comment: This is a bit off topic perhaps, but has anyone noticed that the perspective in above image is backward?

Comment: @romeovs: yes -see Niel de Beaudrap's comment

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: Oops, read over that one. Sorry.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Code saved in** `pgflibrarydecorations.mypathmorphing.code.tex`

```
\usepgfmodule{decorations}

% coilup decoration
%
% Parameters: \pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude, \pgfdecorationsegmentlength,

\pgfdeclaredecoration{coilup}{coil}
{
  \state{coil}[switch if less than=%
    1.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude to last,
               width=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]
  {
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{ 0.555}{1}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0.445}{ 1    }{2}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{ 1    }{3}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{-1    }{9}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0.445}{-1    }{10}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{-0.555}{11}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{ 0    }{12}}
  }
  \state{last}[width=.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude,next state=final]
  {
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{ 0.555}{1}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0.445}{ 1    }{2}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{ 1    }{3}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0    }{6}}
  }
  \state{final}
  {
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}


% coildown decoration
%
% Parameters: \pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude, \pgfdecorationsegmentlength,

\pgfdeclaredecoration{coildown}{coil}
{
  \state{coil}[switch if less than=%
    1.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude to last,
               width=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{1    }{3}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1.555}{ 1    }{4}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0.555}{5}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0    }{6}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{-0.555}{7}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1.555}{-1    }{8}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{-1    }{9}}
  }
  \state{last}[width=.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude,next state=final]
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{ 1    }{3}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1.555}{ 1    }{4}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0.555}{5}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0    }{6}}
  }
  \state{final}
  {
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}

\def\pgfpoint@oncoil#1#2#3{%
  \pgf@x=#1\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude%
  \pgf@x=\pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgf@x%
  \pgf@y=#2\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude%
  \pgf@xa=0.083333333333\pgfdecorationsegmentlength%
  \advance\pgf@x by#3\pgf@xa%
}

\endinput
```

**and highlevel wrapper** `tikzlibrarydecorations.mypathmorphing.code.tex`

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usepgflibrary{decorations.mypathmorphing}

\endinput
```

---

**Usage:**

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.mypathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [decorate, decoration={coil,     aspect=0.4, amplitude=5 mm,  segment length=4mm}, gray, very thick] (0,0) -- (4,0);
\draw [decorate, decoration={coilup,   aspect=0.4, amplitude=5 mm,  segment length=4mm}, red] (0,0) -- (4,0);
\draw [decorate, decoration={coildown, aspect=0.4, amplitude=5 mm,  segment length=4mm}, blue] (0,0) -- (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: color coil]

**Result:**

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.mypathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [decorate, decoration={coilup, aspect=0.4, amplitude=5 mm,  segment length=4mm}] (0,0) -- (4,0);
\filldraw [fill=white] (-1,-0.4) rectangle (5,0.4);
\draw [decorate, decoration={coildown, aspect=0.4, amplitude=5 mm,  segment length=4mm}] (0,0) -- (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: coil wrap]

---

**How it was done:**

@Jan Hlavacek have helped me to find the right file:

```
hpek@melda:/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf$ grep -R coil .|head -1
./libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex:% coil decoration
hpek@melda:/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf$ cp libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex ~/temp/coilMod/
```

and with help from @Andrew Stacey, I maneged to use the file with `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.mydecorations}` with the copied code in `tikzlibrarydecorations.mydecorations.code.tex`. The file was then modified to create the above code.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the horizontal line at the end?

Comment: @mas: Yes. -note that this line segment is precisely the same as in the original coil decoration. You have several options to remove it: You can adjust your endpoint to be a integer multiplum of coils. You can hide the line with clip. You can edit the my code -try removing `\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}`.

Answer (score 34):

Here is a proof-of-concept solution for drawing the coil by parametrizing it and drawing the front and back parts separately using plot paths:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Define a formula for the coil.
    % This is what the numbers mean:
    % 0.3 ... how far the rings are apart
    % 0.4 ... how much from the side the rings are seen (try 0 and the same as the radius)
    % 1.5 ... radius of the rings
    \def\coil#1{
        {0.3 * (2*#1 + \t) + 0.4*sin(\t * pi r))},
        {1.5 * cos(\t * pi r)}
        }

    % Draw the part of the coil behind the rectangle
    \foreach \n in {0,1,...,10} {
        \draw[domain={0:1},smooth,variable=\t,samples=15]
            plot (\coil{\n}); 
        }

    % Draw the rectangle
    \filldraw[fill=white] (-0.5,-1) rectangle (7,1);

    % Draw the part of the coil in front of the rectangle
    \foreach \n in {0,1,...,10} {
        \draw[domain={1:2},smooth,variable=\t,samples=15,
              preaction={draw,white,line width=3pt}     % remove if undesired
             ]
            plot (\coil{\n});
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you for the effort - it is definitely a possible solution, but I was hoping for a modification of the existing coil decoration.

Comment: Would it be possible to add some straight ends to the coil here? Could somebody advise how?

Answer (score 9):

Pgf does not have any user interface for modifying existing decorations.  Your best bet will be creating a new decoration, by starting with the original `coil` decoration and defining two new decorations, say coil-front and coil-back.

To find the definition of the original coil decoration, `cd` to your pgf directory (`/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/` on my system, yours may be different), then run `rgrep coil *`, taht will find number of occurrences of the word `coil`, but luckily all in the same file, `libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex`.  Open that file and search for the word `coil`.  You will then have the original definition of `coil`:

```
% coil decoration
%
% Parameters: \pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude, \pgfdecorationsegmentlength,

\pgfdeclaredecoration{coil}{coil}
{
  \state{coil}[switch if less than=%
    1.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude to last,
               width=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]
  {
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{ 0.555}{1}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0.445}{ 1    }{2}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{ 1    }{3}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1.555}{ 1    }{4}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0.555}{5}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0    }{6}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{-0.555}{7}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1.555}{-1    }{8}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{-1    }{9}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0.445}{-1    }{10}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{-0.555}{11}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{ 0    }{12}}
  }
  \state{last}[width=.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude,next state=final]
  {
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{ 0.555}{1}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0.445}{ 1    }{2}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{ 1    }{3}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1.555}{ 1    }{4}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0.555}{5}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0    }{6}}
  }
  \state{final}
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}

\def\pgfpoint@oncoil#1#2#3{%
  \pgf@x=#1\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude%
  \pgf@x=\pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgf@x%
  \pgf@y=#2\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude%
  \pgf@xa=0.083333333333\pgfdecorationsegmentlength%
  \advance\pgf@x by#3\pgf@xa%
}
```

You will have to make two copies of that, and modify one to draw only the front, the other one to draw only the back.  It will be an interesting exercise in pgf programming.

Comment: `hpek@melda:/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf$ grep -R coil .
./libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex:% coil decoration`