# draw a technical instrument geophone

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

[image]
Could you help to draw the geophone?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}


\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{.71}
    \draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
    \draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;


     \draw[decoration={aspect=.3523, segment length=.6060285mm, amplitude=1.616mm,coil},decorate] (-.35,1.52) -- (-.35,0.4); 
     \draw(-.35,1.52)--(-.35,1.8);
     \draw(-.35,.18)--(-.35,.4);



     \draw[decoration={aspect=.3523, segment length=.6060285mm, amplitude=1.616mm,coil},decorate] (-.35,-3.52) -- (-.35,-4.4); 
     \draw(-.35,-3.52)--(-.35,-3);
     \draw(-.35,-4.4)--(-.35,-4.654);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to write why you want help. I am too lazy is not a valid reason - What is causing you problems? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, exactly the coil,  and the ground as well.

Comment: For the ground, you could use some something like `\draw[decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=0.5pt},decorate]...` or see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39296/simulating-hand-drawn-lines for ideas.

Comment: Now I can draw the ground. How about the shading under the ground?

Answer (score 6):

I am goin to assume, that the problem is to make the coil wrap around the magnet. The solution is described in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43605/8650 (by me).

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\makeatletter

% Decorations based on
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32297/modify-tikz-coil-decoration/43605#43605

% coilup decoration
%
% Parameters: \pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude, \pgfdecorationsegmentlength,

\pgfdeclaredecoration{coilup}{coil}
{
  \state{coil}[switch if less than=%
    1.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude to last,
               width=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]
  {
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{ 0.555}{1}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0.445}{ 1    }{2}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{ 1    }{3}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{-1    }{9}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0.445}{-1    }{10}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{-0.555}{11}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{ 0    }{12}}
  }
  \state{last}[width=.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude,next state=final]
  {
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{ 0.555}{1}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0.445}{ 1    }{2}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{ 1    }{3}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{ 1    }{3}}
    % Uncomment the following lines to close the last loop
    % \pgfpathcurveto
    % {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1.555}{ 1    }{4}}
    % {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0.555}{5}}
    % {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0    }{6}}
    % \pgfpathcurveto
    % {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{-0.555}{7}}
    % {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1.555}{-1    }{8}}
    % {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{-1    }{9}}      
  }
  \state{final}
  {
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}

% coildown decoration
%
% Parameters: \pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude, \pgfdecorationsegmentlength,

\pgfdeclaredecoration{coildown}{coil}
{
  \state{coil}[switch if less than=%
    1.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude to last,
               width=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{1    }{3}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1.555}{ 1    }{4}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0.555}{5}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0    }{6}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{-0.555}{7}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1.555}{-1    }{8}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{-1    }{9}}
  }
  \state{last}[width=.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude,next state=final]
  {
  % Comment the next 5 lines when closing the last loop
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{ 1    }{3}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1.555}{ 1    }{4}}
  {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0.555}{5}}
  {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0    }{6}}
  }
  \state{final}
  {}
}

\def\pgfpoint@oncoil#1#2#3{%
  \pgf@x=#1\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude%
  \pgf@x=\pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgf@x%
  \pgf@y=#2\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude%
  \pgf@xa=0.083333333333\pgfdecorationsegmentlength%
  \advance\pgf@x by#3\pgf@xa%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \draw[decoration={aspect=0.1, segment length=2, amplitude=20 mm, coilup},decorate] (-0.2,-1) -- (-0.2,-2); 

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{.71}
    \draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
    \draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;

\draw[decoration={aspect=0.1, segment length=2, amplitude=20 mm, coildown},decorate] (-0.2,-1) -- (-0.2,-2); 

     \draw[decoration={aspect=.3523, segment length=.6060285mm, amplitude=1.616mm,coil},decorate] (-.35,1.52) -- (-.35,0.4); 
     \draw(-.35,1.52)--(-.35,1.8);
     \draw(-.35,.18)--(-.35,.4);

     \draw[decoration={aspect=.3523, segment length=.6060285mm, amplitude=1.616mm,coil},decorate] (-.35,-3.52) -- (-.35,-4.4); 
     \draw(-.35,-3.52)--(-.35,-3);
     \draw(-.35,-4.4)--(-.35,-4.654);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Coil wrapped around magnet]

Notice that everything between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` is just to make `coilup` and `coildown` work. The rest is not more complicated than your own code.

Comment: How can I move the coill to the left slightly so that the magnet is in the center?

Comment: @Thumbolt: Change the x values! `-0.2` in `\draw[decoration={aspect=0.1, segment length=2, amplitude=20 mm, coildown},decorate] (-0.2,-1) -- (-0.2,-2);`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a proposal with some more explanations and an animation below. Most of the elements are in except for the vertical lines from the terminal to the spiral. This is because I do not understand them, i.e. don't know if these are elements of a 3d picture or just some vertical lines.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d,decorations.pathmorphing}
\makeatletter % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
  \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
  \tikz@canvas@is@plane
}
\makeatother
\pgfkeys{plane scale/.store in=\PlaneScale,
plane scale=1}
\newcommand{\DrawPlane}[4][]{
\draw[canvas is #2,#1] 
({-0.5*\PlaneScale*#3},{-0.5*\PlaneScale*#4}) rectangle
({0.5*\PlaneScale*#3},{0.5*\PlaneScale*#4});
}
\newcommand{\DrawSinglePlane}[2][]{
\ifcase#2
\or
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{60+40*cos(\tdplotmaintheta)}
\DrawPlane[fill=blue!\myint,#1]{xy plane at z=-\cubez/2}{\cubex}{\cubey} % 1st xy plane
\or
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{60+40*cos(\tdplotmaintheta)}
\DrawPlane[fill=blue!\myint,#1]{xy plane at z=\cubez/2}{\cubex}{\cubey} % 2nd xy plane
\or
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{60+40*abs(cos(\tdplotmainphi))}
\DrawPlane[fill=blue!\myint,#1]{xz plane at y=-\cubey/2}{\cubex}{\cubez} % 1st xz plane
\or
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{60+40*abs(cos(\tdplotmainphi))}
\DrawPlane[fill=blue!\myint,#1]{xz plane at y=\cubey/2}{\cubex}{\cubez} % 2nd xz plane
\or
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{60+40*abs(sin(\tdplotmainphi))}
\DrawPlane[fill=blue!\myint,#1]{yz plane at x=-\cubex/2}{\cubey}{\cubez} % 1sy uz plane
\or
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{60+40*abs(sin(\tdplotmainphi))}
\DrawPlane[fill=blue!\myint,#1]{yz plane at x=\cubex/2}{\cubey}{\cubez} % 2nd uz plane
\fi
} 
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{60} % the first argument cannot be larger than 90
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{.71}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{1.2}

\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
% \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
% \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
% \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\path let \p1=(1,0,0)  in 
\pgfextra{\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xproj}{sign(\x1)}\xdef\xproj{\xproj}};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\zproj}{sign(cos(\tdplotmaintheta))}
%\xdef\zproj{\zproj}

% \node[anchor=north west] at (current bounding box.north west)
% {\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,\zproj,\xproj};
%
% lower spiral
\draw (0,0,-4) coordinate (bottom) -- plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi+270:\tdplotmainphi+360] 
({0.2*\R*cos(\x)},{0.2*\R*sin(\x)},{0.1*(\x/360-31)});
\foreach \Y in {-30,-29,...,-20}
{\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+360] 
({0.2*\R*cos(\x)},{0.2*\R*sin(\x)},{0.1*(\x/360+\Y)});}
\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+90] 
({0.2*\R*cos(\x)},{0.2*\R*sin(\x)},{0.1*(\x/360-19)})
-- (0,0,-\cubez/2);
% big spiral in the back
\foreach \Y in {-5,...,5}
{\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180] 
({\R*cos(\x)},{\R*sin(\x)},{0.1*(\x/360+\Y)});}
% cube
\foreach \X in {3,6,2}
    {\DrawSinglePlane{\X}}
\begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=\cubex/2]
\coordinate (plane) at (0,-0.4*\cubez);
\end{scope}
% big spiral in the front
\foreach \Y in {-5,...,5}
{\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi+180:\tdplotmainphi+360] 
({\R*cos(\x)},{\R*sin(\x)},{0.1*(\x/360+\Y)});}
% upper spiral
\draw (0,0,\cubez/2) -- plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi+270:\tdplotmainphi+360] 
({0.2*\R*cos(\x)},{0.2*\R*sin(\x)},{0.1*(\x/360+19)});
\foreach \Y in {20,21,...,30}
{\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+360] 
({0.2*\R*cos(\x)},{0.2*\R*sin(\x)},{0.1*(\x/360+\Y)});}
\draw  plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+90] 
({0.2*\R*cos(\x)},{0.2*\R*sin(\x)},{0.1*(\x/360+31)})
-- (0,0,4) coordinate (top);
% coords
\path ({0.2*\R*cos(\tdplotmainphi+180)},{0.2*\R*sin(\tdplotmainphi+180)},{2.5})
coordinate (spring)
({\R*cos(\tdplotmainphi+230)},{\R*sin(\tdplotmainphi+230)},{0.1*230/360}) coordinate (coil)
({\R*cos(\tdplotmainphi)},{\R*sin(\tdplotmainphi)},{0}) coordinate (right)
({\R*cos(\tdplotmainphi+180)},{\R*sin(\tdplotmainphi+180)},{0}) coordinate (left);
\end{scope}
\draw (left |- bottom) rectangle (right |- top);
\path (top -| left) -- (top -| right) node[fill,inner sep=3pt,above=0pt,pos=0.2] (L){}
 node[fill,inner sep=3pt,above=0pt,pos=0.8] (R){};
\draw (L) -- ++ (0,1) -| node[circle,draw,pos=0.25,fill=white]{A} (R);
\draw (spring) -- ++ (-2.5,0) node[left](spring) {spring}; 
\draw (coil) -- ++ (-2.5,0); 
\node[anchor=west,fill=white] at (spring.west |- coil) {coil};
\draw (R) -- ++ (1.5,0) node[right] (terminal) {terminal};
\begin{scope}
\clip[rounded corners] 
([xshift=-2.8cm]bottom -| left) -- ([xshift=2.8cm]bottom -| right)
|- ++ (-2,-2) -| cycle;
\draw[fill=gray!30,decoration={random steps,segment length=2mm}]
([xshift=-3cm,yshift=-4mm]bottom -| left) [decorate]-- ([xshift=3cm,yshift=-4mm]bottom -|
right) |- ++ (-2,-2) -| cycle;
\end{scope} 
\path (bottom -| left) -- (bottom -| right) 
coordinate[midway,yshift=-1cm] (aux0)
coordinate[midway,yshift=-1.7cm] (aux1)
coordinate[pos=0.4,yshift=-2mm] (aux2)
coordinate[pos=0.6,yshift=-2mm] (aux3);
\draw[fill=gray] (bottom -| left) |- (aux2) 
-- (aux1) -- (aux3) -| (bottom -| right);
\draw (aux0) -- ++ (3,0);
\node[anchor=west,fill=white,align=left] at (terminal.west |- aux0) {spike in\\
ground};
\draw (plane) -- ++ (3,0);
\node[anchor=west,fill=white,align=left] at (terminal.west |- plane)
{oscillating\\ magnet};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is just for fun. In principle you could employ pgfplots for that. I focus on the cube and the spiral.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=8cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={spiralz(\x,\y)=\x/360+\y;}]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{.71}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{2}
\begin{axis}[hide axis,view={40}{35},set layers,
cube/size x=\cubex cm,cube/size y=\cubey cm,cube/size z=\cubez cm]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,10}{
\addplot3[domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}+180},mesh,point meta=x,color=black,
on layer=axis background] ({\R*cos(x)},{\R*sin(x)},{2*spiralz(x,#1)});
}
\addplot3 [only marks,mark=cube*,mark size=7,
on layer=pre main,color=yellow] coordinates {(0,0,10)};
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,10}{
\addplot3[domain={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}+180}:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}+360},mesh,point meta=x,color=black,
on layer=axis foreground] ({\R*cos(x)},{\R*sin(x)},{2*spiralz(x,#1)});
}
%\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/el}}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The advantage of this is that you have orthographic projections and can adjust the view. The disadvantage is the compilation time.

In order to speed up, one can use `tikz-3dplot`, which requires to distinguish 4 cases (in this animation).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d}
\makeatletter % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
  \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
  \tikz@canvas@is@plane
}
\makeatother
\pgfkeys{plane scale/.store in=\PlaneScale,
plane scale=1}
\newcommand{\DrawPlane}[4][]{
\draw[canvas is #2,#1] 
({-0.5*\PlaneScale*#3},{-0.5*\PlaneScale*#4}) rectangle
({0.5*\PlaneScale*#3},{0.5*\PlaneScale*#4});
}
\newcommand{\DrawSinglePlane}[2][]{
\ifcase#2
\or
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{60+40*cos(\tdplotmaintheta)}
\DrawPlane[fill=blue!\myint,#1]{xy plane at z=-\cubez/2}{\cubex}{\cubey} % 1st xy plane
\or
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{60+40*cos(\tdplotmaintheta)}
\DrawPlane[fill=blue!\myint,#1]{xy plane at z=\cubez/2}{\cubex}{\cubey} % 2nd xy plane
\or
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{60+40*abs(cos(\tdplotmainphi))}
\DrawPlane[fill=blue!\myint,#1]{xz plane at y=-\cubey/2}{\cubex}{\cubez} % 1st xz plane
\or
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{60+40*abs(cos(\tdplotmainphi))}
\DrawPlane[fill=blue!\myint,#1]{xz plane at y=\cubey/2}{\cubex}{\cubez} % 2nd xz plane
\or
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{60+40*abs(sin(\tdplotmainphi))}
\DrawPlane[fill=blue!\myint,#1]{yz plane at x=-\cubex/2}{\cubey}{\cubez} % 1sy uz plane
\or
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{60+40*abs(sin(\tdplotmainphi))}
\DrawPlane[fill=blue!\myint,#1]{yz plane at x=\cubex/2}{\cubey}{\cubez} % 2nd uz plane
\fi
} 
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {0,5,...,355}
{\tdplotsetmaincoords{90-40*sin(\X)}{\X} % the first argument cannot be larger than 90
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{.71}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{1.2}

\path[use as bounding box] (-2*\R,-2.4*\R) rectangle (2*\R,2.4*\R);
\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
% \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
% \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
% \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\path let \p1=(1,0,0)  in 
\pgfextra{\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xproj}{sign(\x1)}\xdef\xproj{\xproj}};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\zproj}{sign(cos(\tdplotmaintheta))}
%\xdef\zproj{\zproj}

% \node[anchor=north west] at (current bounding box.north west)
% {\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,\zproj,\xproj};
\ifnum\zproj=1
\foreach \Y in {-5,...,5}
{\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180] 
({\R*cos(\x)},{\R*sin(\x)},{0.1*(\x/360+\Y)});}
\else
\foreach \Y in {-5,...,5}
{\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi+180:\tdplotmainphi+360] 
({\R*cos(\x)},{\R*sin(\x)},{0.1*(\x/360+\Y)});}
\fi

\ifnum\zproj=1
  \ifnum\xproj=1
   \foreach \XX in {2,3,6}
    {\DrawSinglePlane{\XX}}
  \else
   \foreach \XX in {4,6,2}
    {\DrawSinglePlane{\XX}}
  \fi  
\else
  \ifnum\xproj=1
   \foreach \XX in {2,4,6}
    {\DrawSinglePlane{\XX}}
  \else
   \foreach \XX in {3,6,2}
    {\DrawSinglePlane{\XX}}
  \fi  
\fi  

\ifnum\zproj=1
\foreach \Y in {-5,...,5}
{\foreach \Y in {-5,...,5}
{\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi+180:\tdplotmainphi+360] 
({\R*cos(\x)},{\R*sin(\x)},{0.1*(\x/360+\Y)});}
}
\else
\foreach \Y in {-5,...,5}
{\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180] 
({\R*cos(\x)},{\R*sin(\x)},{0.1*(\x/360+\Y)});}
\fi


\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the record: [Jake's patch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/95441) is now incorporated in v3.1 of TikZ.