# How to draw a path alternating in background and foreground?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I would like to draw a spring which "wraps" arround a bar, meaning every alternating line should be drawn on the background. Is is possible to define a tikzstyle for this?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{kinematikz}

\tikzset{
    spring/.style = {
        thick,decorate,green!40!black,decoration={zigzag,amplitude=13,segment length=12}
    },
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (P1) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (P2) at (5,0);
    \pic (bar) at (P1) {link bar generic=P2/0};
    \draw[spring] (P1) -- (P2);
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: output image]

The `kinematikz` package is just for the bar `pic`.

Comment: I don't think you can expect this to be done *automatically*. You may need to draw a bit more manually than with a *decoration*. Maybe a `foreach` loop and some computations.

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32297/modify-tikz-coil-decoration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be an elegant way. But seems worked. You could declare two decoration: one for right slanted spring , one for left slanted spring. Then put one before the bar, the other one after the bar (right slanted spring on the foreground could be better).

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{kinematikz}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{lspr}{initial}
{
\state{initial}[width=12.5pt]
{
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{4pt}{12pt}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{8.5pt}{-12pt}}
}
\state{final}
{
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
}
}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{rspr}{initial}
{
\state{initial}[width=12.5pt]
{
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{4pt}{12pt}}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{8.5pt}{-12pt}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{12.5pt}{0pt}}
}
\state{final}
{
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
}
}

\tikzset{
    rspring/.style = {
        thick,decorate,green!40!black,decoration={rspr, pre length=0.3cm}
    },
    lspring/.style = {
        thick,decorate,green!40!black,decoration={lspr, pre length=0.3cm}
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (P1) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (P2) at (5,0);
    \draw[lspring] (P1) -- (P2);
    \pic (bar) at (P1) {link bar generic=P2/0};
    \draw[rspring] (P1) -- (P2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works great! I would like to make these decorations accept optional values like `amplitude` or `segment length`. Can you tell where I can find information for that?

Comment: @marv Not quite sure about that. You could took a look the pgf manual  "https://ctan.mirror.globo.tech/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf" page. 638 and 1108. Or the link in hpekristiansen's comment.

Comment: Thanks, the comment link is quite usefull. One more question? Why did you add `0.5pt` to all the lengths?

Comment: @marv Those just through trial and error to make each segments looks in a good ratios. You can edit them to make the results as you wanted.  But at least keep them same for both left and right slanted spring.

Comment: With the references you provided it was very easy to parameterize the defintions of the decorations. I have posted the result as a separate answer. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @marv That's nice. I think put some 'pre length=' options will make it looks even better. see my new edits in the answer.

Comment: Great! The only thing I can still think of would be a method which automatically slightly adjusts the `segment length` such that the `post length` matches the desired `pre length`. But it is not that hard to it manually,...

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition to @Tom's very nice answer. With these definitions, it is possible to parameterize the decorations using `amplitude` and `segmengt length`. Their result is stored in the TeX-dimensions `\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude` and `\pgfdecorationsegmentlength` respectively. I also added an argument to the `style` defintions, which makes it possible to locally overwrite the default values.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{kinematikz}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{lspr}{initial}
{
    \state{initial}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]
    {
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecorationsegmentlength/3}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecorationsegmentlength/3*2}{-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    }
    \state{final}
    {
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
    }
}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{rspr}{initial}
{
    \state{initial}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]
    {
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecorationsegmentlength/3}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecorationsegmentlength/3*2}{-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0pt}}
    }
    \state{final}
    {
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
    }
}

\tikzset{
    rspring/.style = {
        thick,decorate,green!40!black,decoration={rspr, amplitude=12pt, segment length=12pt, #1}
    },
    lspring/.style = {
        thick,decorate,green!40!black,decoration={lspr, amplitude=12pt, segment length=12pt, #1}
    },
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (P1) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (P2) at (5,0);
    \draw[lspring] (P1) -- (P2);
    \pic (bar) at (P1) {link bar generic=P2/0};
    \draw[rspring] (P1) -- (P2);
    
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-1.2cm]
        \coordinate (P3) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (P4) at (5,0);
        \draw[lspring={amplitude=14pt, segment length=17pt}] (P3) -- (P4);
        \pic (bar) at (P3) {link bar generic=P4/0};
        \draw[rspring={amplitude=14pt, segment length=17pt}] (P3) -- (P4);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: different springs]

I am once again amazed how easy and flexible `TikZ/PGF` is!