How to draw a helical tube around a cylinder?
I'm trying to create this image:

But i couldn't find a way to draw a helical tube (Xe-flash lamp) around the ruby rod. How can i do that?
My current code:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[americanresistor]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{
    decorations,
    decorations.pathmorphing,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=snake, thick]
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (2, 6.75) ellipse (.5 and .75) ++ (0, -.75) -- ++(10, 0);
        \draw (2, 7.5) -- ++(10, 0) ++ (0, -.75) ellipse (.5 and .75);
        
        % circuit
        \draw (4.5, 4.5) -- ++(0, -1.5) coordinate (a) to[C, l^=Capacitor] ++(5, 0) coordinate (b) -- ++(0, 1.5);
        \draw (a) |- ++(1.25, -1.75) to[battery, l_=Power supply] ++(1, 0) to [R] ++(2, 0) -| (b);
        \draw[<-] (1.75, 6.2) -- ++(-1, -1) node[align=center, anchor=east] {Fully\\ silvered\\ end};
        \draw[<-] (3.5, 7.5) -- ++(-.5, 1) node[align=center, anchor=south] {Ruby rod};
        \draw[<-] (12.2, 6.2) -- ++(.5, -1) node[align=center, anchor=north] {Partially\\ silvered\\ end};
        
        \draw[decorate, ->] (12, 7) -- ++(1.25, 0);
        \draw[decorate, ->] (12, 6.8) -- ++(1.25, 0) node [anchor=west, align=left] {Laser\\ beam};
        \draw[decorate, ->] (12, 6.6) -- ++(1.25, 0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



From an artistic point of view you should be more consistent with the choice and application of perspective. E.g. on end of the rod is inconsistent. Perhaps 2D engineering drawings are better (e.g. front, side) ? // Suggestion: Try getting photos from the first lasers of this kind. Try sketching on paper, first, to understand the relevant parts from an artistic view.

@MS-SPO sure. I just come up with this simple working example to make a starting point.

There are several of these question - search for transformer/coil or look at this question/answer of mine and follow related links: Modify TikZ coil decoration
Here is a start - adjust parameters and add aspect to make it look good:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[americanresistor]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{
decorations,
decorations.pathmorphing,
}

\makeatletter
% Decorations based on
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32297/modify-tikz-coil-decoration/43605#43605

% coilup decoration
%
% Parameters: \pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude, \pgfdecorationsegmentlength,

\pgfdeclaredecoration{coilup}{coil}
{
  \state{coil}[switch if less than=%
    1.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude to last,
               width=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]
  {
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{ 0.555}{1}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0.445}{ 1    }{2}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{ 1    }{3}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{-1    }{9}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0.445}{-1    }{10}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{-0.555}{11}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{ 0    }{12}}
  }
  \state{last}[width=.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude,next state=final]
  {
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{ 0.555}{1}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0.445}{ 1    }{2}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{ 1    }{3}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{ 1    }{3}}     
  }
  \state{final}
  {
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}

% coildown decoration
%
% Parameters: \pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude, \pgfdecorationsegmentlength,

\pgfdeclaredecoration{coildown}{coil}
{
  \state{coil}[switch if less than=%
    1.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude to last,
               width=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{1    }{3}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1.555}{ 1    }{4}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0.555}{5}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0    }{6}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{-0.555}{7}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1.555}{-1    }{8}}
    {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{-1    }{9}}
  }
  \state{last}[width=.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+%
    \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude,next state=final]
  {
  % Comment the next 5 lines when closing the last loop
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{ 1    }{3}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1.555}{ 1    }{4}}
  {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0.555}{5}}
  {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0    }{6}}
  }
  \state{final}
  {}
}

\def\pgfpoint@oncoil#1#2#3{%
  \pgf@x=#1\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude%
  \pgf@x=\pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgf@x%
  \pgf@y=#2\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude%
  \pgf@xa=0.083333333333\pgfdecorationsegmentlength%
  \advance\pgf@x by#3\pgf@xa%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=snake, thick]
\draw[decorate, decoration={coildown, amplitude=1.4cm, segment length=1.2cm}] (3,6.75) --(12,6.75);
\draw[decorate, decoration={coildown, amplitude=1.1cm, segment length=1.2cm}] (3.2,6.75) --(12,6.75);
\fill[white] (3,6) rectangle (11,7.5);
\draw (2, 6.75) ellipse[x radius=0.5, y radius=0.75] ++ (0, -0.75) -- ++(10, 0);
\draw (2, 7.5) -- ++(10, 0) ++ (0, -.75) ellipse[x radius=0.5, y radius=0.75];
\draw[<-] (1.75, 6.2) -- ++(-1, -1) node[align=center, anchor=east] {Fully\\ silvered\\ end};
\draw[<-] (3.5, 7.5) -- ++(-.5, 1) node[align=center, anchor=south] {Ruby rod};
\draw[<-] (12.2, 6.2) -- ++(.5, -1) node[align=center, anchor=north] {Partially\\ silvered\\ end};
\draw[decorate, ->] (12, 7) -- ++(1.25, 0);
\draw[decorate, ->] (12, 6.8) -- ++(1.25, 0) node [anchor=west, align=left] {Laser\\ beam};
\draw[decorate, ->] (12, 6.6) -- ++(1.25, 0);
\draw[decorate, decoration={coilup, amplitude=1.4cm, segment length=1.2cm}] (3,6.75) --(12,6.75);
\draw[decorate, decoration={coilup, amplitude=1.1cm, segment length=1.2cm}] (3.2,6.75) --(12,6.75);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Almost close. Is there any way to somehow remove overlap of two helixes in the top part?

Yes - you could adjust aspect or segment length to remove this overlap, and make the coils more parallel.

I tried some combination of commands and got exactly what I wanted. Thanks @hpekristiansen for the answer. I solved the overlapping problem by making the helix to have a large line width and stroke color to white.Then I added two more helix to draw a outline.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[americanresistor]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
decorations,
decorations.pathmorphing,
patterns
}%
\begin{document}%
\makeatletter%
% Decorations based on
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32297/modify-tikz-coil-decoration/43605#43605
% coilup decoration
%
% Parameters: \pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude, \pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
\pgfdeclaredecoration{coilup}{coil}{
    \state{coil}[switch if less than=
        1.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength+
        \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+
        \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude to last,
        width=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]
    {
        \pgfpathcurveto
        {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{ 0.555}{1}}
        {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0.445}{ 1    }{2}}
        {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{ 1    }{3}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{-1    }{9}}
        \pgfpathcurveto
        {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0.445}{-1    }{10}}
        {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{-0.555}{11}}
        {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{ 0    }{12}}
    }
    \state{last}[width=.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength+
        \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+
        \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude,next state=final]
    {
        \pgfpathcurveto
        {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0    }{ 0.555}{1}}
        {\pgfpoint@oncoil{0.445}{ 1    }{2}}
        {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{ 1    }{3}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{ 1    }{3}}
    }
    \state{final}
    {
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
    }
}
% coildown decoration
%
% Parameters: \pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude, \pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
\pgfdeclaredecoration{coildown}{coil}
{
    \state{coil}[switch if less than=
        1.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength+
        \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+
        \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude to last,
        width=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]
    {
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{1    }{3}}
        \pgfpathcurveto
        {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1.555}{ 1    }{4}}
        {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0.555}{5}}
        {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0    }{6}}
        \pgfpathcurveto
        {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{-0.555}{7}}
        {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1.555}{-1    }{8}}
        {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{-1    }{9}}
    }
    \state{last}[width=.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength+
        \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+
        \pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude,next state=final]
    {
        % Comment the next 5 lines when closing the last loop
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint@oncoil{1    }{ 1    }{3}}
        \pgfpathcurveto
        {\pgfpoint@oncoil{1.555}{ 1    }{4}}
        {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0.555}{5}}
        {\pgfpoint@oncoil{2    }{ 0    }{6}}
    }
    \state{final}
    {}
}
\def\pgfpoint@oncoil#1#2#3{%
    \pgf@x=#1\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude%
    \pgf@x=\pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgf@x%
    \pgf@y=#2\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude%
    \pgf@xa=0.083333333333\pgfdecorationsegmentlength%
    \advance\pgf@x by#3\pgf@xa%
}%
\makeatother%
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=snake]
    \coordinate (tube start) at (3.2,6.75);
    \coordinate (tube end) at ($(tube start) + (9, 0)$);

    % right side of coils
    \draw[decorate, decoration={coildown, amplitude=1.1cm, aspect=0.5, segment length=1cm}, line width=3mm, white] (tube start) -- (tube end);
    \draw[decorate, decoration={coildown, amplitude=1.25cm, aspect=0.57, segment length=1cm}, black] ($ (tube start) + (-.15, 0) $) -- (tube end);
    \draw[decorate, decoration={coildown, amplitude=.95cm, aspect=0.43, segment length=1cm}, black] ($ (tube start) + (.15, 0) $) -- (tube end);
    % extra bit that extends to bottom
    \draw[fill=white]
    ($ (tube end) + (-.224, 0)$) .. controls ++(-.1, -.6) and ++(.2, .5) .. ++(-.5, -1.7) coordinate (tube right start)
    -- ++(-.3, 0) coordinate (tube right end) .. controls ++(.25, .5) and ++(0, -.3) .. ($ (tube end) - (.533, -.02) $);

    % rod
    \draw[fill=pink!45, opacity=1, stroke=black] (1.7, 7.5) -- ++(10.7, 0) arc (90:-90:.5 and .75) -- ++(-10.7, 0) arc (270:90:.5 and .75);
    \fill[opacity=.4, pink] (1.7, 6.75) ellipse (.5 and .75);
    \fill[opacity=.7, pattern=north west lines] (12.4, 6.75) ellipse (.5 and .75);
    \draw[opacity=.1] (1.7, 7.5) arc (90:-90:.5 and .75);
    \draw[opacity=.8] (12.4, 7.5) arc (90:270:.5 and .75);

    % left side of coils
    \draw[decorate, decoration={coilup, amplitude=1.1cm, aspect=0.5, segment length=1cm}, line width=3mm, white] (tube start) -- (tube end);
    \draw[decorate, decoration={coilup, amplitude=1.25cm, aspect=0.57, segment length=1cm}, black] ($ (tube start) + (-.15, 0) $) -- (tube end);
    \draw[decorate, decoration={coilup, amplitude=.95cm, aspect=0.43, segment length=1cm}, black] ($ (tube start) + (.15, 0) $) -- (tube end);
    % extra bit that extends to bottom
    \draw[fill=white]
    ($ (tube start) + (.15, 0) $) .. controls ++(-.1, -.6) and ++(-.2, .2) .. ++(.2, -1.7) coordinate (tube left start)
    -- ++(-.3, 0) coordinate (tube left end) .. controls ++(-.3, .5) and ++(-.04, -.3) .. ($ (tube start) - (.147, -.02) $);

    % circuit
    \filldraw (tube left start) rectangle ($(tube left end) - (0, .05)$);
    \filldraw (tube right start) rectangle ($(tube right end) - (0, .05)$);
    \draw (tube left end) ++(0.15, 0) -- ++(0, -.5) -| (4.5, 4.5) -- ++(0, -1.5) coordinate (a) to[C, l^=Capacitor] ++(5, 0) coordinate (b) -- ++(0, 1.5) -| ($(tube right end) + (.15, 0)$);
    \draw (a) |- ++(1.25, -1.75) to[battery, l_=Power supply] ++(1, 0) to [R] ++(2, 0) -| (b);

    % labels
    \draw[<-] (1.75, 6.2) -- ++(-1, -1) node[align=center, anchor=east] {Fully\\ silvered\\ end};
    \draw[<-] (2.7, 7.5) -- ++(-.5, 1) node[align=center, anchor=south] {Ruby rod};
    \draw[<-] (8, 8) -- ++(.5, .7) node[align=center, anchor=south] {Xenon flash lamp};
    \draw[<-] (12.2, 6.2) -- ++(.5, -1) node[align=center, anchor=north] {Partially\\ silvered\\ end};

    \draw[red, decorate, ->] (12.6, 7) -- ++(1.25, 0);
    \draw[red, decorate, ->] (12.6, 6.8) -- ++(1.25, 0) node [anchor=west, align=left] {Laser\\ beam};
    \draw[red, decorate, ->] (12.6, 6.6) -- ++(1.25, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}


